# How can I clean this picture up (opencv-python)?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am really new to opencv. How can I remove the noise in the background without losing info?

I started with this: and Otsu thresholded it. I've tried erosion, dilation, bilateral filtering. My goal is to get a rectangle on the borders so I can perspective transform the thresholded picture, but it has trouble finding contours. Or maybe is there a different and better approach?

Comment: The most different thing you could do at this point is take the highest quality/resolution and highest contrast pictures possible, preferably against a very different coloured background, because image processing is pretty much a Garbage In Garbage Out sort of process. Also avoid jpeg if you can (or use the lowest possible compression setting if that’s all you can do) because it introduces encoding artifacts you intentionally shouldn’t be able to see but which do affect image processing algorithms.

Comment: @barny thanks for the advice! Unfortunately this is not a picture I took or can retake. I will try to find better ones that fit my purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Blur it
- Convert to HSV and extract the saturation channel
- Threshold the saturation image
- Clean it up with morphology close and open and save as a mask
- Recreate your OTSU threshold image
- Write black to OTSU image where mask is black (zero)
- For comparison, write black to Input image where mask is black (zero)
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('circuit_board.jpg')

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)

# convert to hsv and get saturation channel
sat = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]

# threshold saturation channel
thresh = cv2.threshold(sat, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology close and open to make mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# do OTSU threshold to get circuit image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
otsu = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# write black to otsu image where mask is black
otsu_result = otsu.copy()
otsu_result[mask==0] = 0

# write black to input image where mask is black
img_result = img.copy()
img_result[mask==0] = 0

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("circuit_board_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("circuit_board_otsu.png", otsu)
cv2.imwrite("circuit_board_otsu_result.png", otsu_result)
cv2.imwrite("circuit_board_img_result.png", img_result)


# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("SAT", sat)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("OTSU", otsu)
cv2.imshow("OTSU_RESULT", otsu_result)
cv2.imshow("IMAGE_RESULT", img_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask image:

[image]

OTSU threshold image:

[image]

OTSU Result:

[image]

Image Result:

[image]